# How Can implement FriendShip with CakePHP Model?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, relational-database

In the CakePHP Documentation they implement this as below !!

```
class Message extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Sender' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        ),
        'Recipient' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'recipient_id'
        )
    );
}
```

and

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'MessageSent' => array(
            'className' => 'Message',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        ),
        'MessageReceived' => array(
            'className' => 'Message',
            'foreignKey' => 'recipient_id'
        )
    );
}
```

But this didn't work with me !!
and give me some errors that there's some tables in the User Model is not found !!
this will work just if I use the name of HasMany to the same name of the Model !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling searchs with fail !!
I just go to the easiest ways !!

```
public $hasMany = array(


     'Follow_me'=>array(
         'className'=>'Friend',
         'foreignKey'=>'user_to' ,
             ) , 

      'Follow_them'=>array(
         'className'=>'Friend2',
         'foreignKey'=>'user_from'
      ) );
```

this is the User Model 
and
Class User

now the Friend Model

```
   public $belongsTo = array(


      'User'=>array(
         'className'=>'User',
         'foreignKey'=>'user_from' , 
        ) , 


   );
```

the table of friends will be

id || user_from || user_to || created || modified

now with the easiest way !!
Create a new Model Class with the name Friend2

```
public $useTable = 'friends';
   public $belongsTo = array(


      'User'=>array(
         'className'=>'User',
         'foreignKey'=>'user_to' , 

      ) , 


   );
```

now !!
when you fetch from the User Model the Data will be like that

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'User' => array() ,
                'Follow_me' => array() ,
              'Follow_them' => array() , 
              'Some_Other_Relations_Goes_here' => array() 
) )
```

Hope this will Help you All